# Is there a surjection f:[0,1]→[0,1] such that f(x)∈Q for every irrational number x∈[0,1]?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The infinite set has a countable subset, so we can choose a countable subset from [0,1] \ Q, and this subset will have a bijection with [0,1] ∩Q. All numbers that are not in this subset will be reset to zero. Why is this example wrong?

Comment: Not a surjection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardinality of $f([0,1])$ is bounded by the greatest cardinality between $f(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])$ and $f([0,1]\setminus \mathbb{Q})$. Now, the cardinality of $f(\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])$ is trivially bounded by the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, if $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ maps all irrational numbers to rational numbers, then the cardinality of $f([0,1])$ is bounded by the cardinality of $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular, $f$ cannot be surjective.